# Is copy-pasting many folders in Nautilus problematic in terms of memory / CPU operations?

Tags: nautilus, backup

I was wondering if copy-pasting a folder with a big number of files and sub-folders, using Nautilus, is problematic or inefficient in terms of memory or CPU operations, compared to the conventional way through the terminal? What are the differences if there are?